# Autofill, Autocomplete in all browsers in form in fancybox

Tags: html, forms, autofill

Hi I have the following problem. I am building a form inside a div which initially is with display:none; inside that form I have two fields - e-mail and password like this:

```
<form id="formino" name="blah" action="" autocomplete="on"><input type="text" name="emal" id="maila" autocomplete="on"> .................. </form> ....
```

So in that way the integrated in the browser autocomplete(autofill) doesn't work no matter what I do.
The doctype is html5. The html is perfectly constructed. It never worked before . The browser is thousand times checked and is with the best settings for that with all the privacy stuff done right (IE,FF,Chrome).

Please don't suggest "we need more info, etc , etc". Assume that everything is ok with the code.
Again:
Fancybox, div - display:none; form , inputs, AJAX after button click, bind on the submit() with return false;

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? Something? :)

Comment: you probably tried already, but did you try removing "display:none"? or you have more inputs with same name?